# Template with more parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to do a multiuse debug function. This works but now i'd like to add 2 things:

1. Make it work with a variable number of different parameters.
2. Add the output of the name of the variable, as example: a: 42   b[0]: 54

   > ```
   > template<bool B> struct Print {};
   >
   > template<> struct Print<true> {
   > template<class T> static int do_it (T a)  { cout << a << endl; }
   > };  
   >
   > template<> struct Print<false> {
   >   template<class T> static int do_it (T & a) {
   >       for (int _n(((int)((a).size()))-1), i(0); i <= _n; i++)
   >           cout << *(next(a.begin(),i)) << endl;
   >               cout << endl; 
   >   }
   > };
   >
   > template<class T>
   > int debug (T A){
   >        return Print<std::is_scalar<T>::value>::do_it( A ) ;
   > }
   >
   > int main(){
   >   int a = 42;
   >   vector <int> b;
   >   b.push_back(54);
   >     debug(a); // Works
   >   debug(b); // Works
   >     debug(a,b); //It's what i'm trying to do.
   >   return 0;
   > }
   > ```

PS: c++11

Comment: Since you're using C++11 you can use [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Comment: Variadic templates give you the means to provide multiple arguments but they won't deal with the variable names: there is nothing in the core language dealing with the names. However, a variadic macro in combination with a variadic template and a simple helper may do the trick (haven't use variadic macros, yet - maybe a good opportunity to try that space out...)

Comment: `int _n(((int)((a).size()))-1)` wtf?

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious && (at)Dietmar Kuhl I'll take a look to variadic templates, I think it's what i was looking for but i'll try it before to be sure.

Comment: @Loopunroller This is because it comes from a the output of the preprocessor defines that i used :P for me it's just FOR(array) but i put the "whole" code to not have to include all the defines i use too..

Comment: @Casey just realized ^^ you're in right but seems that people here has understand me what i was looking for, next time i'll try to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concentrating on the aspect of adding variable names and supporting arbitrary number of arguments, you can use variadic macros to get hold of the names and variadic templates to get hold of all arguments. It doesn't attempt to integrate writing sequences but this can easily be incorporated by not using `operator<<()` directly but rather format the value conditionally. Here is an example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <int I, int N>
struct debugger
{
    template <typename Args>
    static void print(std::vector<std::string> const& names, Args const& args) {
        std::cout << names[I] << '=' << std::get<I>(args) << ' ';
        debugger<I + 1, N>::print(names, args);
    }
};

template <int N>
struct debugger<N, N>
{
    template <typename Args>
    static void print(std::vector<std::string> const&, Args const&) {
    }
};

template <typename... N, typename... A>
void print_debug(char const* str, std::tuple<A...> const& args)
{
    std::istringstream in(str);
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    for (std::string name; std::getline(in >> std::ws, name, ','); ) {
        names.push_back(name);
    }
    debugger<0, std::tuple_size<std::tuple<A...>>::value>::print(names, args);
    std::cout << '\n';
}

#define debug(...) print_debug(#__VA_ARGS__, std::tie(__VA_ARGS__))


int main()
{
    int    i(17);
    double d(3.14);
    debug(i, d);
}
```

Comment: @Dietman Kuhl I've just seen your code. I've copy/pasted him and try it just to try if it was working for "not scalar" variable too. It doesn't do but I think that you gave me all that i was looking for so now I'll put it on my code and i'll let you know :) (Better like this, so I can do my part too ^^)

Comment: I'm stuck here, can you help me or i've to do another question? `template<const int N> struct debugger {
 template <typename Args> static void work_it(Args const& wake){
  Print< std::is_scalar < tuple_element<N,Args>::type > ::value > ::do_it ( get<N>(wake) ) ; //Gives an error
 }
};
   
template<typename... T>
void print_debug (const char* ss,tuple<T...> args){
 for(int i=0;i<sizeof...(T);i++)
  debugger<tuple_size<tuple<T...>>::value>::work_it(args);
 return;
    //return Print<std::is_scalar<T>::value>::do_it( A ) ;
}`

Comment: @UmurilLyerood: it's a bit unclear what the error is. From a cursory look it seems there is `typename` missing in front of `tuple_element<N,Args>::type`.